# Facebook share from within an Iframe which directs to a Parent page

Tags: javascript, html, facebook-graph-api, iframe

We have parent page with an Iframe in it.
We want people to use a Facebook share button (using Addthis.com) within the iframe, and that the share will:

1. Get the parent page URL, and link the share to the father page
2. Will get the title, description and thumbnail from the iframe page
3. I understand Facebook Open Graph can help but dont know how.

Comment: if you are using `addthis.com widget` for sharing, won't the share contents depend on the implementation of the widget? perhaps you can get help from their [support team](http://support.addthis.com/)

Comment: Is the parent page on the same domain as the page in the iframe?

Comment: If you are sharing the parent page then the description, title and thumbnail of the parent page will be used during sharing. There is no way to change that. Facebook will get those info from the meta tags of the exact page that is shared.